# Saving Canvas as a Bitmap without drawing it again

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

My app draws onto a `Canvas`, which I then want to save on the SD card.  This is not a problem, however when I save the image it draws the `Canvas` again and saves it in the file.  The problem is that the program uses random factors in creating the image, therefore when it's redrawn it is a different image to that shown on the screen.

Does anyone know who to save the image on the screen without the system drawing it again?

Thanks

Comment: Android canvas or HTML5 canvas?